# GPO is not Deleting Certain Scheduled Tasks

Tags: windows, gpo

Active Directory Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Clients: Windows 7 x64

I've created a GPO that is intended to delete three scheduled tasks. The GPO is being applied correctly, and it successfully deletes one of the three scheduled tasks. However, the other two tasks remain and event viewer logs show no errors (just that GPO was applied successfully).

I've doubled checked the actual task names and the task names specified in the GPO; they match.

The only difference I can think of is that the one task that was deleted successfully was set to run as "SYSTEM" and the other tasks that are not being deleted by GPO are set to "Run only when user is logged on".

I can remotely connect to these computers via "Computer Management" and delete the tasks as Domain Admin.

Any idea what might be going wrong with the GPO here? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone reading this, the fix was this: Before deleting some tasks via GPO, you have to first disable those tasks via GPO (when prompted for the program to be run, I just used cmd.exe). Doing this successfully deleted all desired tasks upon next gpupdate.   ... I only discovered this through trial and error - hope it helps someone!

Comment: You should answer your own question if your comment is a solution...